# C#: Breakpoint is never reached and Picturebox Image does not change

Tags: c#, image, debugging, resources, picturebox

i was trying to add some kind of advent calender to my programm.
So i created a second form with the designer.
After clicking a toolstripmenuitem following gets executed.

```
private void OpenAdventCalender()
{
  if (fAdvent == null)
  {
       fAdvent = new Advent();
       fAdvent.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(fAdvent_FormClosed);
       AdventOptions[0] = "1";
       fAdvent.Visible = true;
   }
}
```

Now that works fine. The Form does open and i can doubleclick picktureboxes.
On a doubleclick the image of the picturebox should change.
I tried it like that:

```
private void ShowAdventMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(false){}  //in original code i test on 24 days and pictureboxes
    else if ((DateTime.Today >= DateTime.Parse("01.12.2016")) && (sender == pictureBox1))
    {
        fForm1.AdventOptions[1] = "1";
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        pictureBox1.Image = Resources.p1;
        pictureBox1.Update();
        MessageBox.Show(fForm1.AdventList[0]);  //This Message pops up correctly
    }
}
```

So the first big Problem is that the pictureBox1 does not change the image.
It also does not get deletet if i set the picturebox to null.
In the constructor im changing it the first time, there it works. Outside the constructor it does not work.

Now the second problem. I cannot debug in there. Breakpoints in the constructor or in any other function of my second form are never reached. Since i know that that Messagebox pops up i know it does reach the code.

When i hover over the breakpoint with my mouse, it told me:

> The breakpoint cannot be reached at the moment. The code is differnt to the original version.

It also told me that i can change something in options to reach the breakpoints.
So i changed "Extras - Options - Debugging - General - Sourcefiles must be exactly like the original version = deactivated".
After that the breakpoints were still unreachable.  Now the message from the breakpoint was:

> The breakpoint cannot be reached at the moment. There is no executable code with the targetcodetype of the debugger connected with this line.

Does someone know how to debug in there?
Or does someone know what i am doing wrong so that the image does not change?

What i use if needed:
 - Windows 10 professional 64bit
 - Visual Studio 2015
 - Resharper Ultimate

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I know a silly question, but i just wanted to check:
Have you got your project running in "Release" mode?

if so, change it back to debug.

Comment: There are no silly questions. Sadly it is not that easy. Im running it in debug mode. Also Breakpoints in Form1 do work.

Comment: If you change fAdvent.Visible = true; to fAdvent.Show() does that help?

Comment: No, that did not change anything.

Comment: Shove a breakpoint on fAdvent.Show(), then use F11 to follow the code, do you see it reach your intended destination?   -   I've never seen VS say it cannot debug because the code is different, very strange.

Comment: Wow. Did not expect that to happen.[link](https://pl.vc/qftmn).  The Error says something like: It automatically jumped over an property or operator. I try to do what the message says to change that behavior.

Comment: That pretty much is the same error as before "I cannot debug the thing you're trying to make me debug, so i'm going to skip over it.".   Create a new form with nothing in it, and attempt to load it the same way, are you able to debug a brand new form?

Comment: Err. Okay. I still cannot jump into the show(). but i tried now with a new form and it startet to throw that same message every third line. then i commented my fAdvent out so that only the new testform was created. it jumped to the breakpoint that was still in the commented code. Then i rightclicked my project in projectexplorer and fully compiled it.... Then it was able to jump into the test form. after that enabled my fAdvent again and i was able to debug it, and the picturebox changed like it should. So it works now. Whatever the problem was.

Comment: I guess Visual Studio threw it's toys out of the pram, haha.
Maybe a good idea to check for any VS Updates via Windows Update (ensure you have applications updating as well as windows fixes as well), or update to the latest version of VS.

Strange though, glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

After testing if i also cannot debug a complete newly created form, i compiled it fully through project explorer. After that it worked.